Direct initialisation from user-defined conversion optimizes away intermediate object
I was looking for a way to inplace initialize a tuple and found this posted solution which relies on conversion between classes.
I'd like to know what rules are applying that leads to intermediate object "elision".
I built this minimal example to illustrate may question.
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>

class To {
   public:
    To() { std::puts("default constructor"); }
    explicit To(int input) : val(input) { std::puts("value constructor"); }
    // noexcept is a sweet lie because of std::puts
    To(To&& object) noexcept : val(object.val) {
        std::puts("move constructor");
    }
    // noexcept is a sweet lie because of std::puts
    To& operator=(To&& object) noexcept {
        val = object.val;
        std::puts("move assign");
        return *this;
    }
    ~To() noexcept { std::puts("destructor"); }

   private:
    int val = -1;
};

class From {
   public:
    explicit From(int input) : val(input) {
        std::puts("From value constructor");
    }
    // marking explicit to inhibit to1 assignement
    operator To() const&& { return To{val}; };

   private:
    int val = -1;
};

To Make_To(int val) { return To{val}; }

int main() {
    std::puts("-----------------");
    std::puts("# direct init with conversion");
    const std::tuple<To> tp0{From{0}};
    std::puts("# direct init with creator");
    const std::tuple<To> tp1{Make_To(1)};
    std::puts("# init and assign");
    std::tuple<To> tp2;
    tp2 = From{2};
    std::puts("# finish");
}

Live C++17
(I'm using C++17 for guaranteed RVO).
The output is:
-----------------
# direct init with conversion
From value constructor
value constructor
# direct init with creator
value constructor
move constructor
destructor
# init and assign
default constructor
From value constructor
value constructor
move assign
destructor
# finish
destructor
destructor
destructor

I let the create and assign as a reference for a situation where RVO cannot fully apply as the destination object as already started its lifetime.
Why is there a difference between the initialization from conversion and the initialization from creator?

[EDIT] extended example
Instead of a std::tuple, I'm now using a simple wrapper:
struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper(To&& Input) : val(Input) {
        std::puts("Wrapper To&& constructor");
    };
    Wrapper(const To& Input) : val(Input) {
        std::puts("Wrapper const To& constructor");
    };

   private:
    To val;
};

int main() {
    std::puts("-----------------");
    std::puts("# Wrapper direct init with conversion");
    const Wrapper d0(From{0});
    std::puts("# Wrapper direct init with creator");
    const Wrapper d1(Make_To(1));
    std::puts("-----------------");
    std::puts("# finish");
}

Live
The output is now:
-----------------
# Wrapper direct init with conversion
From value constructor
value constructor
copy constructor
Wrapper from To&& constructor
destructor
# Wrapper direct init with creator
value constructor
copy constructor
Wrapper from To&& constructor
destructor
-----------------
# finish
destructor
destructor

Which is quite different from the std::tuple version, whereas I expected the same output. How is it so?

As always, initialization in c++ is overly complicated.

@JeJo A Make_To function should make a To, not a From.

Possibly relevant: temporary materialization - since this ensures "guaranteed copy elision".

@Eljay are you speaking of "Note that temporary materialization does not occur when initializing an object from a prvalue of the same type (by direct-initialization or copy-initialization): such object is initialized directly from the initializer. This ensures "guaranteed copy elision"." But I don't get why Make_To return is not elided according to this wording

I'm partially answering to my own edit: Wrapper is missing a converting constructor that can accept a From. Only a constructor for a To object can accept the result of a conversion to To, can't it? I think that it's in the rule for direct init, and conversion chains...

There aren't any rules that say that: Formally, direct-initializing a To with an argument of type From selects the move constructor, and calls the move constructor with a temporary made by calling From::operator To().
This is CWG2327, and some people are trying to address this by adding extra initialization rules, which you can see here: P2828.
Compilers already implement the expected behaviour where To(from_object) works exactly the same as To(from_object.operator To()).

As for the difference you've seen, const std::tuple<To> tp1{Make_To(1)}; calls the tuple constructor template that takes a To&&, so there must be a temporary to bind to the rvalue reference. This rvalue reference is then used to initialise the element of the tuple, calling the move constructor.
const std::tuple<To> tp0{From{0}}; calls the constructor that takes a From&&. The element of the tuple is initialized from this rvalue reference, which doesn't call the move constructor (the target of operator To() is the member of the tuple, so there is nothing to move from, which is nonstandard but that's what the compilers do).
